# configure webpack for not bundle angularjs library

Tags: angularjs, webpack

I have an AngularJS (1.5.8) application and I use webpack to create a bundle of all the libraries needed by the application itself.
For some technical reasons, I need not to bundle angularjs library in my application bundle but, instead, to use angular lib which is imported as a script tag in my index.html
Is that possible with webpack?

Thanks,
Gab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is [externals](https://webpack.github.io/docs/library-and-externals.html)

> `externals` allows you to specify dependencies for your library that are not resolved by webpack, but become dependencies of the output. This means they are imported from the environment during runtime.

Since you did not post your current config, I cannot show you how to add this to it. It's usually straightforward, just read the docs.

if externals are already defined somewhere:

```
webpackConfig.externals.angular = 'angular';
```

if you are defining them:

```
webpackConfig.externals = {angular: 'angular'};
```

Make sure the angular script is included before the bundle.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks